# Extract Object properties for use in an array

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have a JSON string with some values that I unserialized into an object (STDClass/Object).

There are a couple of values in it, but I have to extract exactly 8 of those values into an multidimensional array. This snippet shows the values I'm after as they existed in the JSON:

```
"picture1":"path/to/image/picture1.jpg"
"picture1_color":"#000000"
"picture2":"path/to/image/picture2.jpg"
"picture2_color":"#111111"
"picture3":"path/to/image/picture3.jpg"
"picture3_color":"#222222"
"picture4":"path/to/image/picture4.jpg"
"picture4_color":"#333333"
```

I want to extract these values and put them into an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [picture] => path/to/image/picture1.jpg
            [color] => #000000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [picture] => path/to/image/picture2.jpg
            [color] => #111111
        )

and so forth


)
```

Is this doable programmatically or do I just need to do it by hand?

Comment: By hand? How would you go about doing that? With a paper and pen?

Comment: just extracting it manually i mean ofcourse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with all conditions you've provided (your original data structure, un-serialization into an object instead of an array, etc.), and assuming they're all non-negotiable, this is how I would extract the pieces you're looking for:

```
$json_serialized_input = '{"something":"foo","something_else":"bar","picture1":"path/to/image/picture1.jpg","picture1_color":"#000000","picture2":"path/to/image/picture2.jpg","picture2_color":"#111111","picture3":"path/to/image/picture3.jpg","picture3_color":"#222222","picture4":"path/to/image/picture4.jpg","picture4_color":"#333333"}';  

$input = json_decode($json_serialized_input);

$output = [];
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $current_picture_property = 'picture' . $i;
    $current_color_property = $current_picture_property . '_color';

    $output[] = [
        'picture' => $input->{$current_picture_property},
        'color' => $input->{$current_color_property},
    ];
}

var_dump($output);
```

This is just a procedural example of the concepts. In an actual program I'd make a function/method that takes the input and produces the output. That function might even take starting and ending numbers to loop for, and maybe some sort of params for specifying a template for the property names. That all depends on how general purpose your needs are or are not.

Anyway, the code I gave above should produce:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["picture"]=>
    string(26) "path/to/image/picture1.jpg"
    ["color"]=>
    string(7) "#000000"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["picture"]=>
    string(26) "path/to/image/picture2.jpg"
    ["color"]=>
    string(7) "#111111"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["picture"]=>
    string(26) "path/to/image/picture3.jpg"
    ["color"]=>
    string(7) "#222222"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["picture"]=>
    string(26) "path/to/image/picture4.jpg"
    ["color"]=>
    string(7) "#333333"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah this is the way to go. I have to check if the number and picture is existing because sometimes there are only 3 or 2 pictures defined instead of 4. But i can make it work, thanks for the insight.

Comment: Ha, I almost suggested a check for whether they're set. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to do have the JSON as a string:

```
$myData = '[{"picture1":"path/to/image/picture1.jpg","picture1_color":"#000000"},{"picture2":"path/to/image/picture2.jpg","picture2_color":"#111111"},{"picture3":"path/to/image/picture3.jpg","picture3_color":"#222222"},{"picture4":"path/to/image/picture4.jpg","picture4_color":"#333333"}]';
```

Then Decode the JSON string to an array:

```
print_r(JSON_decode($myData, TRUE));
```

Which while produce the following PHP array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [picture1] => path/to/image/picture1.jpg
        [picture1_color] => #000000
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [picture2] => path/to/image/picture2.jpg
        [picture2_color] => #111111
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [picture3] => path/to/image/picture3.jpg
        [picture3_color] => #222222
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [picture4] => path/to/image/picture4.jpg
        [picture4_color] => #333333
    )

)
```

I use json_encode and json_decode all the time and it comes in really handy when  using PHP with Node.js and js in general.

Comment: Your output differs slightly from the OP's desired output. Note that he wants the key names of `picture` and `color` in the resulting second dimension arrays of the output.

Comment: Yep, yours was spot on!  Thanks.